# Insert SQL statement conditionally

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

How can I insert run a SQL statement conditionally and return the final state of the command?

- Table has columns `id`, `value`, `active` (no unique constraints on the table)
- Want to do `insert into mytable (id, value) values (5, 'text')`
- Should not insert if any rows match `value = 'text'` and `active is not null`

  - If there were matching rows, want to distinguish if any of the matching rows had an `id` of `5` (the id being inserted), versus if all of the matching rows had `id` of other than `5`

So there are 3 final states, and the calling application should be able to easily distinguish between these 3 states.

- inserted
- didn't insert because any of the matching rows had an `id` of `5`
- didn't insert but none of the matching rows had an `id` of `5`

Comment: Have a stored procedure or a trigger to validate and store in the table.

Comment: Create a stored procedure with pretty simple IF/ELSE conditions and return what you need as a final value depends on conditions.
1. [Tutorial sproc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_functions.htm) 2. [Tutorial if/else](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-if-else-statements/)